# How to break long sentences into sentences of 5 to 10 words and have good results with LSTM's?

Tags: machine-learning, text, nlp, deep-learning

The projects that I am working on will have sentences with 5 to 10 words as input in real life.
But I'm training on Guttenberg books and it has very long sentences.
I will loose 90% of data if I extract only sentences with 5 to 10 words.
What is the best way to break a long sentence?

What I'm thinking of is

"w1 w2. .... ... ... ......w18" 
into

sentence 1: START w1 ............w9

sentence 2: w10 ............. w18 END

Can I do this and get away with good results with LSTM?

Comment: What do you mean by "good results"? What are you trying to actually do? Whatever it is, if you need training data for modern user input splitting up sentences from public domain books isn't a good way to get it!

Comment: I mean getting good accuracy. I'm building a text generator. which needs sentences to be between 5 to 10 words. But I'm finding it hard to find data set with just 5 to 10 words. So I thought of breaking these long sentence into sentences of 10 words.

Comment: @polm23 do you have any suggestions on where i can find data with this condition?

Answer (score 3):

There are a few solutions here.

The optimal one, in my opinion, is to ditch your current ML library and switch to [pyTorch](https://pytorch.org/). PyTorch is a modern, well-documented library undergoing rapid development that supports dynamic computational graphs. In essence, this means you may define a process that takes inputs of arbitrary length and produces outputs of also arbitrary length. An official tutorial for Seq2Seq LSTM for text generation can also be found [here](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/intermediate/seq2seq_translation_tutorial.html).

Another solution (assuming you are using Keras/TF) would be to employ [stateful LSTMs](https://philipperemy.github.io/keras-stateful-lstm/), i.e. LSTMs that keep their hidden state and context vectors through different samples.

Finally, perhaps the easiest solution would be to find a sequence length that achieves a good balance between computational expenses and ratio of samples kept. This would require you to visualize the distribution of sentence lengths and figure out where the sweet spot (for your needs) is.